# How to Get All POST Variables In A Request

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to work my way through some web scraping stuff with the requests library and I've stumbled across encrypted POST data. What I'd like to do is programmatically find a way to retrieve the key names of the POST variables so that I could send my own unfiltered values through. Is there a way to do this and could someone explain it to me or point me in the right direction?

```
import requests

s = requests.Session('http://thiswebsite.com/login', auth=('username','password'))

# Find some way to determine what k is for POST variables in k,v

params = {
    'INeedThis' : 'So I can pass this',
    'AndAlsoThis' : 'So I can pass this too',
    'AndSoOn' : 'etc'
}

x = post('http://thiswebsite.com/anotherpage', params)
print x.status_code
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You're the one passing the "POST variables" in.

Comment: What do `x.text()` and `x.json()` return?

Comment: Are you asking to get all post variable..?

Comment: open url in Chrome/Firefox and use `DevTools` (built-in in browser) to see what data is send by browser. Then you have to use the same in your code.

Comment: if you what to find programmatically then you have to `get()` page with `form` and use HTML parser (ie. `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup`) to find all tags inside `<form>` tag (like browser do).

Comment: @furas I think you have the answer I'm looking for. I'm already using bs4 for something else; I guess I can just make a regex object to search for what I need. Thank you!

Comment: If you use `bs4` so why do you want ot use regex. `bs4` can be more usefull - you have to find all `<input>` and `<button>` in `<form>` and get their `name=`. If page doesn't use JavaScript to add elements then it should work.

Comment: You're right and I'm new to this. I'll attempt a solid bs4 only approach for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need names of data sends by `POST` then you have to first `GET` this page and find all `<input>`, `<button>`, `<text>` in  `<form>`

For example - login page on facebook.com

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.facebook.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for x in soup.find_all('form'):
    for i in x.find_all(['input', 'button', 'text']):
        print(i.name, i.get('name'))
    print('---')
```

result:

```
input lsd
input email
input pass
input None
input persistent
input default_persistent
input timezone
input lgndim
input lgnrnd
input lgnjs
input ab_test_data
input locale
input next
---
input lsd
input firstname
input lastname
input reg_email__
input reg_email_confirmation__
input reg_passwd__
input sex
input sex
button websubmit
input referrer
input asked_to_login
input terms
input ab_test_data
input contactpoint_label
input locale
input reg_instance
input captcha_persist_data
input captcha_session
input extra_challenge_params
input recaptcha_type
input captcha_response
button None
---
```

As you see there are many `input`s so sometimes it is better to use `browser` manually and see what "names" are send from browser to server :)